# Adding a fixed ID to Body in Wordpress via functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Should be fairly simple and have had a good search around the web, but most solutions are too complex.

Trying to implement a jquery menu system and need to add a body ID to the main body of my Wordpress site in order to target by ID, easier I think that way.

I would like to add this via functions.php to avoid touching the theme header files directly in child theme incase of updates etc.

So far I have the below - doesn't seem to be working though haha, so I've clearly missed something obvious!

Trying to target all pages, then add the id 'st-container'

Thanks in advance:

```html
// create a custom function
function my_custom_body_id($id) {
    if ( is_page() )  $id = 'st-container';
    return $id;
};
add_filter('body_id','my_custom_body_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_class_names' );
function my_class_names( $classes ) {
    // add 'st-container' to the $classes array
    if(is_page()) {
      $classes[] = 'st-container';
    }
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

Give that a go - you need to return an array

Comment: Thanks buddy I am actually using this, this is for a class - I am trying to add an ID though if possible :)

Comment: Just re-read that, oops, can you not target the body by class then?

Comment: I guess I could do that yeah! Do you think ID will be significantly harder? I tried to use $id instead of $classes? and add filter 'body_id' :/

Comment: Yeah I am just having a look and don't think its easy without actually editing the header template. I would stick with the class unless its absolutely essential to use an id. Plus if you have the standard WP tags going in all pages will already have a body class of "page" so you don't even need an extra function.

Comment: Alright mate fair shout, thanks for your input I'll see what I can do with that - I have actually just thought the same RE the page class :) We're based in Ashburton in Devon btw, I see you are Bristol based :)

Comment: `jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
 jQuery( 'body' ).attr('id', 'st-container');
 });` - Alternative solution too, not the cleanest way of doing it though through js.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of JS but that seems counter intuitive... but if it works for you. I am from Newton Abbot so know Ashburton well :)

Answer (score 0):

template (header.php)

```
<body <?php body_id(); ?>>
```

functions.php

```
    function body_id() {
    if( is_page_template('page-service.php') ) {
        $id = 'id="service-page"';
    }

    echo $id;
}
```

my view-source output was

```
<body id="service-page">
```